# Converting from Numpy.zeros(100,100) to using a Scipy.sparse.lil_matrix(100,100) Error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am creating a finite volume solver, and had success using numpy.zero to create a zero matrix and used a for loop to fill specific locations of the matrix with values that I wish to calculate.

However, I need to use a larger matrix specifically numpy.zeros(102400,102400) but I get the error "Array too Big" I can do a numpy.zeros(10000,10000) matrix but that seems like the limit of my system (6 GB Ram).

I was told changing the matrix into a sparse matrix would free space for my code, and all me to do the calculations. However **my code that initially was created to fill a zero matrix can not be used on this sparse matrix, and I don't know why.**

```
import numpy as np

import scipy as sp

from scipy import sparse

matA = sp.sparse.lil_matrix(m, m)

matb = sp.sparse.lil_matrix(m, 1)

i = 0

for row in range(Lrow):

    for column in range(Lcol):

        if row == 0 and column == 0:  

            matA[i, i + 1] = -k * (delY / delX)  

            matA[i, i + Lcol] = -k * (delX / delY)  

            matA[i, i] = -(3 * matA[i, i + 1] + matA[i, i + Lcol])
```

edit: my m = 100000 and i get iterated each time  at the end of the if statement by i = i + 1

Comment: If you haven't used `sparse` matrices before, play around with small ones that you can display and test.  Try the different initialization methods show in the docs.  Look at the different formats.  `lil` is ok for iterative definition, But even if you get this working, you'll come back with a question complaining about slow speed.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your sparse matrices incorrectly. Take a look a the documentation for [`lil_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.lil_matrix). Given that `m` is your shape parameter you actually want to initialize the matrix as follows (note that the first argument is a tuple):

```
matA = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((m, m))
matA
<100000x100000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

The way you are doing it you end up with a 1x1 matrix, which I assume is not your intent:

```
matA = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix(m, m)
matA
<1x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

The reason for this is that the first argument for `lil_matrix` is looking for an array, or array-like, another sparse matrix, or a tuple. When you enter `lil_matrix(m,m)` it essentially ignores the second argument, as the first is interpreted as an array-like, and just initializes a 1x1 array with the value set to `m`.